# Maven: Package Does Not Exist. Dependencies Seem Correct

Tags: java, maven

Hello I'm trying to run `mvn clean install`, and I'm receiving a package does not exist error:

```
[DEBUG] Source roots:
[DEBUG]  /Users/username/Projects/Venice/clarity/clarity-test-e2e/src/test/java
[DEBUG] Command line options:
[DEBUG] -d /Users/username/Projects/Venice/clarity/clarity-test-e2e/target/test-classes -classpath /Users/username/Projects/Venice/clarity/clarity-test-e2e/target/test-classes:/Users/username/Projects/Venice/clarity/clarity-test-e2e/target/classes:/Users/username/.m2/repository/uk/co/jemos/podam/podam/7.0.5.RELEASE/podam-7.0.5.RELEASE.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/net/jcip/jcip-annotations/1.0/jcip-annotations-1.0.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.22/slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/jsr250-api/1.0/jsr250-api-1.0.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.5/commons-lang3-3.5.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/testng/testng/6.11/testng-6.11.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/com/beust/jcommander/1.64/jcommander-1.64.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.17/snakeyaml-1.17.jar:/Users/username/Projects/Venice/clarity/clarity-etl/target/clarity-etl-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/Users/username/Projects/Venice/clarity/clarity-statusserv/dao/target/clarity-statusserv-dao-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/Users/username/Projects/Venice/clarity/clarity-statusserv/model/target/clarity-statusserv-model-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-collections4/4.1/commons-collections4-4.1.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.4.1.Final/hibernate-validator-5.4.1.Final.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.3/classmate-1.3.3.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.16.12/lombok-1.16.12.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.3/httpclient-4.5.3.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.6/httpcore-4.4.6.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10/commons-codec-1.10.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-log4j2/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-log4j2-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.7/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.7.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.7/log4j-api-2.7.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-core/2.7/log4j-core-2.7.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.22/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.22/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.22.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-couchbase/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-data-couchbase-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-web-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.13.0.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.13.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/com/couchbase/client/java-client/2.3.7/java-client-2.3.7.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/com/couchbase/client/core-io/1.3.7/core-io-1.3.7.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/io/reactivex/rxjava/1.1.8/rxjava-1.1.8.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.8.6/jackson-databind-2.8.6.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.8.0/jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.8.6/jackson-core-2.8.6.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.5.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.11/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.11.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.5.11/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.11.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.5.11/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.11.jar:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar: -sourcepath /Users/username/Projects/Venice/clarity/clarity-test-e2e/src/test/java: -s /Users/username/Projects/Venice/clarity/clarity-test-e2e/target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations -g -nowarn -target 1.8 -source 1.8 -encoding UTF-8
[DEBUG] incrementalBuildHelper#beforeRebuildExecution
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to /Users/username/Projects/Venice/clarity/clarity-test-e2e/target/test-classes
[DEBUG] incrementalBuildHelper#afterRebuildExecution
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/username/Projects/Venice/clarity/clarity-test-e2e/src/test/java/com/company/consumer/tools/clarity/e2e/etl/ETLHappyPathSuite.java:[6,58] package com.company.consumer.tools.clarity.etl.dao.v1.state does not exist
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Clarity - Parent Pom ............................... SUCCESS [  0.256 s]
[INFO] Clarity - Status Service Parent Pom ................ SUCCESS [  0.007 s]
[INFO] Clarity - Status Service Model ..................... SUCCESS [  2.416 s]
[INFO] Clarity - Status Service DAO Components ............ SUCCESS [  0.693 s]
[INFO] Clarity - Status Service ........................... SUCCESS [  2.119 s]
[INFO] Clarity - Checkstyle Configuration ................. SUCCESS [  0.034 s]
[INFO] Clarity - ETL ...................................... SUCCESS [  0.776 s]
[INFO] Clarity - Testing E2E .............................. FAILURE [  0.216 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.039 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-05T11:47:36-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 47M/536M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project clarity-test-e2e: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/username/Projects/Venice/clarity/clarity-test-e2e/src/test/java/com/company/consumer/tools/clarity/e2e/etl/ETLHappyPathSuite.java:[6,58] package com.company.consumer.tools.clarity.etl.dao.v1.state does not exist
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project clarity-test-e2e: Compilation failure
/Users/username/Projects/Venice/clarity/clarity-test-e2e/src/test/java/com/company/consumer/tools/clarity/e2e/etl/ETLHappyPathSuite.java:[6,58] package com.company.consumer.tools.clarity.etl.dao.v1.state does not exist

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
/Users/username/Projects/Venice/clarity/clarity-test-e2e/src/test/java/com/company/consumer/tools/clarity/e2e/etl/ETLHappyPathSuite.java:[6,58] package com.company.consumer.tools.clarity.etl.dao.v1.state does not exist

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:858)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.TestCompilerMojo.execute(TestCompilerMojo.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :clarity-test-e2e
```

The dependency pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>



    <!-- ================================================================== -->
    <!-- Parent -->
    <!-- ================================================================== -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.company.consumer.tools.clarity</groupId>
        <artifactId>clarity-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>



    <!-- ================================================================== -->
    <!-- Application Description -->
    <!-- ================================================================== -->
    <artifactId>clarity-etl</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Clarity - ETL</name>
    <description>
    </description>

    <properties>
        <app.mainClass>com.company.consumer.tools.clarity.etl.ETLMain</app.mainClass>
        <docker.image.prefix>dockerhub.companycorp.com/username</docker.image.prefix>
    </properties>


    <!-- ================================================================== -->
    <!-- Dependencies -->
    <!-- ================================================================== -->
    <dependencies>

        <!-- ================================================================== -->
        <!-- Clarity Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.consumer.tools.clarity</groupId>
            <artifactId>clarity-statusserv-dao</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ================================================================== -->
        <!-- Test Dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>



    <!-- ================================================================== -->
    <!-- Build -->
    <!-- ================================================================== -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- ================================================================== -->
            <!-- Invoke spring boot application. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${app.mainClass}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.4.13</version>
                <configuration>
                    <imageName>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                    <dockerDirectory>src/main/docker</dockerDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                            <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                    <useConfigFile>true</useConfigFile>
                    <registryUrl>https://dockerhub.companycorp.com/</registryUrl>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now

```
  [username]@[localhost] (master)$jar -tf 
/Users/username/.m2/repository/com/company/consumer/tools/clarity/clarity-
etl/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/clarity-etl-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep dao
BOOT-INF/classes/com/company/consumer/tools/clarity/etl/dao/
BOOT-INF/classes/com/company/consumer/tools/clarity/etl/dao/v1/
BOOT-INF/classes/com/company/consumer/tools/clarity/etl/dao/v1/state/
BOOT-INF/classes/com/company/consumer/tools/clarity/etl/dao/v1/
state/EtlStateDocument.class
BOOT-INF/classes/com/company/consumer/tools/clarity/etl/dao/v1/
state/EtlStateRepository.class
```

After running `mvn dependency:build-classpath` I can see `clarity-etl-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` (the dependency) is on the classpath.

Here is the dependent pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>



    <!-- ================================================================== -->
    <!-- Parent -->
    <!-- ================================================================== -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.company.consumer.tools.clarity</groupId>
        <artifactId>clarity-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>



    <!-- ================================================================== -->
    <!-- Project Settings -->
    <!-- ================================================================== -->
    <artifactId>clarity-test-e2e</artifactId>
    <name>Clarity - Testing E2E</name>
    <description>
        The end to end testing for Clarity.
    </description>
    <properties>
        <org.apache.maven.surefire.version>2.19.1</org.apache.maven.surefire.version>
    </properties>


    <!-- ================================================================== -->
    <!-- Distribution Management -->
    <!-- ================================================================== -->
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>releases</id>
            <name>Internal Nexus Releases</name>
            <url>http://nexus.company.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>Internal Nexus Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://nexus.company.com/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>



    <!-- ================================================================== -->
    <!-- Repositories -->
    <!-- ================================================================== -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>company-nexus</id>
            <name>company Nexus</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://nexus.company.com/nexus/content/groups/public-all/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>uk.co.jemos.podam</groupId>
            <artifactId>podam</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.consumer.tools.clarity</groupId>
            <artifactId>clarity-etl</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- ================================================================== -->
    <!-- Build -->
    <!-- ================================================================== -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>e2e</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.apache.maven.surefire.version}</version>
                        <dependencies>
                            <dependency>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                                <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
                                <version>${org.apache.maven.surefire.version}</version>
                            </dependency>
                        </dependencies>
                        <configuration>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <dbhost>${dbhost}</dbhost>
                                <dbuser>${dbuser}</dbuser>
                                <dbpass>${dbpass}</dbpass>
                                <saasEndpoint>${saasEndpoint}</saasEndpoint>
                                <cssEndpoint>${cssEndpoint}</cssEndpoint>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                            <parallel>all</parallel>
                            <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
                            <properties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>suitethreadpoolsize</name>
                                    <value>20</value>
                                </property>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

I'm not sure why this is not building correctly using `mvn clean install` from command line, but it appears to work perfectly fine when I execute from eclipse. I think Eclipse, by default, provides all classes on classpath (regardless of scope), but I've tried different scopes to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Notice the classes in the jar are under BOOT-INF/classes/. I'm afraid the compiler cannot see them - they must be under the root of the jar. BOOT-INF is used by Spring Boot.

Comment: This is probably the correct observation. I'm wondering, how would I include the spring-boot app in my e2e test? Any thoughts?

Comment: Looks like this question has answered the exact thing I'm asking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40089443/how-to-add-a-dependency-to-a-spring-boot-jar-in-another-project

Comment: If your goal is to test a Spring Boot application (not just to use a Spring Boot app jar as a dependency), then Spring Boot provides powerful tools for doing it AFAIK. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html

Comment: Thanks vempo. If you want, please go ahead and refer to the stackoverflow.com question I've posted in an answer to this question. I'll give you credit for this question, as I do believe you got me on the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `clarity-etl-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` as a regular jar dependency. Notice that the classes in this jar are under `BOOT-INF/classes`, which is used by Spring Boot but ignored by the Java compiler.

If your goal is to test the Spring Boot application (as opposed to using the jar as a dependency), then Spring Boot provides easy ways to do it.
 See, for example https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html.

If, on the other hand, it is important to include the classes in another application, then [How to add a dependency to a Spring Boot Jar in another project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40089443/how-to-add-a-dependency-to-a-spring-boot-jar-in-another-project) might help as you pointed out in the comments.