# Spring boot Maven MultiModule Rest api Call

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

All I'm new on Spring boot and have a question.
Currently I'm working with the spring boot multi module project.
I have 3 spring boot project.

like A,B,C, each have rest-controller like below:-

**--------------------Project-A----------------------------------**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/demoa")
public String demoa() {
    return "demoa";
}
```

**--------------------Project-B----------------------------------**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/demob")
public String demob() {
    return "demob";
}
```

**--------------------Project-C----------------------------------**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/democ")
public String democ() {
    return "democ";
}
```

I add the both (B, C) project as a mavend dependency in Project(A) and compiled all

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.b</groupId>
    <artifactId>demob</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c</groupId>
    <artifactId>democ</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

after that i run my project like "mvn Spring-boot run" it run on 8080.
When i call the "Rest /demoa" it give me the response while when i try to call other rest it show these
error below:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-04-25T14:47:56.816+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/demob"
}
```

My Question is how I get the response of both 2 api while running the project"A"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a dependency to a Spring Boot Jar in another project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40089443/how-to-add-a-dependency-to-a-spring-boot-jar-in-another-project)

Comment: I solve this issue in 2 way look link below

Comment: https://github.com/NABEEL-AHMED-JAMIL/pdftest/tree/master/demo%20folder

Comment: https://github.com/NABEEL-AHMED-JAMIL/pdftest/tree/master/multi-mudule

Comment: Hi @NabeelAhmed, what is the core solution?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your controllers in `Project A` and `Project B` are scanned and autoconfigured.
What you need to do is to use the `@ComponentScan` annotation in your main class and give it packages on Components and Controllers in the `Project A` and `Project B`

Comment: hello, how can I do this?

Answer (score -2):

For `/demob` and `/democ`. You need to run the corresponding projects or:

You can:

- deploy all projects in your single tomcat server.
- Deploy a load balancer from your hosting provider, or you can use `Nginx` for doing that.
- Have three tomcat servers.
- Have single spring boot project but three Rest controllers.