# Making one module depend on another module artifact?

Tags: maven

I have created one spring boot maven project. There is one parent pom.xml. Parent pom has 4 modules. Following is the parent pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.8</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>xyz</name>
    <description>xyz project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
        <project.version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</project.version>
        <spock-spring.version>2.1-groovy-3.0</spock-spring.version>
        <gmavenplus-plugin.version>1.13.1</gmavenplus-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>...</dependencies>
    <modules>
        <module>xyz-common</module>
        <module>xyz-notification</module>
        <module>xyz-issue</module>
        <module>xyz-logger</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

In xyz-notification module there is a dependency of xyz-common.
Following is the pom of xyz-common:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
        <artifactId>xyz-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>xyz-common</artifactId>
    <name>xyz-common</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <description>xyz Common Module</description>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

Following is the pom of xyz-notification:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
        <artifactId>xyz-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>xyz-notification</artifactId>
    <name>xyz-notification</name>
    <description>xyz notification module</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xyz</groupId>
            <artifactId>xyz-common</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency> ...
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

First common is build `mvn -pl xyz-common clean install`
and then xyz-notification `mvn -pl xyz-notification clean install`

But I am getting an error while building xyz-notification:

```
Failed to execute goal on project xyz-notification: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.xyz:xyz-notification:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.xyz:xyz-common:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.xyz:xyz-common:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.xyz:xyz-parent:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT ->
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Spring Boot JARs as dependency in other JARs. They are not normal library JARs.

Comment: What could be done?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40089738/927493

Comment: The solution is I have added repackage in pom.xml of xyz-common